# pgAdmin4で、restore,backupができなくなった。何か見落としている？

Tags: postgresql

Windows10でPostgresql9.6を使っています。
サーバーのDatabaseをbackupしてローカルにrestoreしてサービス対応するような仕事をしています。
数日前から、pgAdmin4からのbackup,restoreができなくなりました。Job createdのメッセージは出るのですが、jobが開始される気配がありません。
コマンドラインからのpg_dump、pg_restoreは機能するので、postgresql側の問題ではないと思います。
また、pgAdmin4を再インストールしてみましたが、状況は変わりません。
設定など触ったわけではないと思いますが、何か見落としているのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 私はpgAdminIIIしか使ったことが無いのですが、お使いになっているpgAdmin4はデスクトップモードとサーバモードがあるそうですし、バージョンによっても動きが違うとのことですので、ご使用中のバージョンと、モード、pgAdmin4でどこまでできて何ができないか、などを判る範囲で追記していただいた方が第三者から見て状況が掴みやすいのではないかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。pgAdminのバージョンは4.25です。server_modeはfalseです。モニターやテーブル参照、クエリーツール等は普通に使えています。症状ですが、Backupの場合、JobCreatedのメッセージ表示後、通常ならば進行状況を示すダイアログが表示されるところですが、これは表示されません。ただし0biteのファイルが作成されています。当たりをつけるほど使い込んでいないのでなかなか要領を得ないかと思いますが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
設定(Preference)から、バイナリーの実行パスを現行使用しているPostgresのbinに設定し直したところ正常になりました。
設定がずれていた理由、これまで問題なく動いていた理由は不明です。